# .net 4 CAS: Remove specific privilege

Tags: .net, .net-4.0, code-access-security

I'm trying to create a web service interface for an internal application. I have to reuse a lot of old stuff which, among other things, have calls to MessageBox.Show() in various places which I have to use. I try to validate the input to not hit those calls, but I can't be certain that I succeed.

Therefore, I thought about denying the UIPrivilege. I do like this:

```
void DoSomething() {
    new UIPermission(UIPermissionWindow.NoWindows).PermitOnly();
    DoTheRealWork();
}
```

This works in the sense that it does not allow any UI, but it also disallows unrelated privileges which the code needs (eg. OleDbPermission). How can I deny the UIPermission only, not touching any other permissions (the code has full trust).

(`UIPermission.Deny()` is obsolete in .net framework 4 and gives an error when used, so it is not a valid answer).

Answer (score 0):

What exactly are you trying to accomplish?  Your web service should not be running in UserInteractive mode<sup>1</sup>, so it should be throwing a runtime exception if the code attempts to show a message box.  This is the same behaviour you would see if you did restrict permissions successfully (aside from the exception details), so why bother with the permission restriction kludge?

---

<sup>1</sup>A web service deployed under IIS will, by default, not run as user-interactive.  However, if you are running under the Cassini development web server, this will not be the case, so you should check the behaviour under IIS deployment.